# Printing missed letter array in Hangman.java

Tags: java

I am making the Hangman game and its going good so far. I just want to declare and print an array of Missed Letters. Missed Letters are the letters which user has already inputted.

Here is the code:

```
   public static void chosenWord()  throws IOException{

    String randomWord="";
    Scanner ui = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    randomWord = word.get(rand.nextInt(word.size()));

    String Dashes = new String(new char[randomWord.length()]).replace("\0", "_");
    while(Tries < 6 && Dashes.contains("_")) {
        System.out.print("Guess a Character :");
        System.out.print(randomWord);
        System.out.println(Dashes);
        String guess = ui.next();
        char[] Misses = new char[6];
        String chngeDashes = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < randomWord.length(); i++) {
            if (randomWord.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(0)) {
                chngeDashes += guess.charAt(0);
                System.out.print("Guesses: "+guess.toUpperCase());
            } 
            else if (Dashes.charAt(i) != '_') {
                chngeDashes += randomWord.charAt(i);
            } else {
                chngeDashes += "_";
            }
        }

        if (Dashes.equals(chngeDashes)) {
            Tries++;
            Misses[Tries] = guess.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Misses: "+Misses[Tries]); //Want to print missed letters
            //gameOver();
        } else {
            Dashes = chngeDashes;
        }
        if (Dashes.equals(randomWord)) {
            System.out.println("Correct! You win! The word was " + randomWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just loop through misses and print out each letter?

Comment: You told us what you want - what's the problem in making it happen?

Comment: Use lower/camel case for your instantiated variables. `String dashes = ...` not `String Dashes = ...`

Comment: Hey, I tried that but it prints 6 times instead of one time. Also, it does not save the words in array.

Comment: @csmckelvey Actually I am unable to print the misses array. I tried to spot the mistake but I can't. When I printout the array it prints 6 times or leaves a big gap.

Comment: Use print instead of println

Comment: @AdamS I did it and it fixed the print issue, but it still doesn't save the letters user entered. My output is:                                       `Guess a Character :date____
q
Misses: q

Guess a Character :date____
w
Misses: w`

Comment: You are creating the misses array every single iteration, so it will not save anything beyond a single iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Also, if you print out as you are (assuming you fix re-creating the misses array during each try), it will only print a single letter (the last one missed), unless you use what I wrote in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. You should clarify your question as a part of the question, not expect people to read through the code.  Properly explain what your current behavior is, and what behavior you are currently experiencing.

B.  I think what you are looking for is: "Arrays.toString(Misses)" (at least as you improperly have it named)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Portion A is a comment, but B is an answer.

Comment: @wrestang I am sorry, but I am new in stack overflow and getting used to the format. But I understand what you said. Thanks! :)

Comment: @HumxaFaroooq No worries, just as some advice, we can't help you if we don't know what you actually need help with.

Comment: Currently you are just printing the exact missed variable, where I assume you would like to print out all missed characters.  If you replace "Misses[tries]" with "Arrays.toString(Misses)" it will (to quote the javadoc) "Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array" see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[])

Comment: @wrestang Actually I figured it out. I was successful in printing the array using "Arrays.toString(Misses)". I was just missing 's' :P

Comment: Cool, accepting my answer if it did indeed answer your question would be appreciated in return :)

Comment: @wrestang Yup Thanks man. It really worked. Now I am having one more issue. If the user Guesses a word, program shows "Guess: ". If the word contains duplicate letters, The "Guess: " statement prints multiple times. Thanks :)

Comment: So, instead of just outright giving you the answer at this time, I want to provide you with a helpful exercise.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging.  Do you understand what your for loop is doing exactly?  Do you understand exactly why you are printing out "Guesses" even once?  I really think that once you think about those two things you will see how it could be printed multiple times.  It might also be helpful for your own understanding if you write out a comment for each condition in the for loop what would allow that condition to be true.

Comment: I think once you can understand what the for loop and and if statements are doing, think about this next: How do I keep track of a particular condition, how long (scope) should I know about that condition?  I can't in good conscience just outright answer you without knowing you understand all of those things.